# Flutter - wordpress comments + widget.post.title + widget.post.link as share function

Tags: wordpress, flutter, comments, share

I would like to provide the comments of my flutter wordpress app in connection with the associated post and link `widget.post.title` `widget.post.link` for the share function, but unfortunately I don't know how to do this correctly.

The code below shows roughly how I like it, but the `widget.post.title` `widget.post.link` is not accepted because I have to import this somehow first, hope someone can help me

```
    child: ClipOval(
      child: Material(
        color: Color(0xFF282C39),
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.blue,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 25,
            height: 25,
            child: Icon(
                Icons.share,
                size: 16,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Share.share(
                widget.post.title + ' ' + widget.post.link + ' ' + comment.authorName.toUpperCase() + ' ' + comment.date + ' ' + comment.content);
            },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

I succeeded in sharing the comments without reference to the article in so far as unfortunately `<br>` and `<aref>` are also displayed there, but I think that's another problem, just wanted to mention it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of your onTap function?

You can try writing it this way:

```
 OnTap: ( ) {
 String sharedContent = widget.post.title + ' ' 
 +widget.post.link + ' ' + comment.authorName.....etc;
 Share.share(sharedContent);}
```

What happens this way? Can you post more details?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot include "widget.post.link" & "widget.post.title" in my comment screen as it is highlighted in red. With "comment.authorName, comment.date, comment.content" it works "halfway", with the exception that <br> <aref> <p> </a> and some other HTML things are the result of sharing. Unfortunately, the proposed method did not lead to success, but thank you anyway

Comment: Post your entire code for this widget screen. Since comment is working without widget.comment, remove widget from post.title and post.link. are you using statless widget? If so, you don't need widget keyword.